# Effective send big array of coordinates using Socket.io

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, sockets, socket.io

I was testing performance of my node.js server and I detected that this small code last too much time:

```
socket.emit("a",{a1:something,a2:veryBigArray});
```

Problem is that my array is very big and socket.io must encode it to JSON.
My array is something like:

```
veryBigArray=[{x:0,y:0},{x:0,y:1},{x:1,y:1},{x:1,y:2}.......];
```

I am interested mainly in server performance. I want server can continue in work as soon as possible.

Before sending array to client, I generate array, so I don't have problem to completely change structure of sended data. Maybe array could be somehow compressed. I read about ArrayBuffer;

What is the best (fastest for sever) way of sending big array of coordinates to client (browser) using Socket.io?

Comment: How "big" are we talking? Kilobytes? Megabytes?

Comment: 250 000 coordinates for example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you must encode the array to JSON then I don't think an ArrayBuffer will help. However, if you know the precise data structure of the array to be sent and can predict it server-side, you can come up with your own efficient encoding/decoding schema.

In your example, your data is simply an array of `x` and `y` value pairs where each value is an integer. An extremely simple but possibly fruitful approach would be to strip the data of the predictable (unnecessary) `x` and `y` keys and encode it as a simple CSV (comma-separated value) string.

For example:

`[{x:0,y:0},{x:0,y:1},{x:1,y:1},{x:1,y:2}]`

would encode as the string:

`0,0,0,1,1,1,1,2`

The most efficient approach however would probably be to abandon socket.io for your own custom websocket interface that can somehow send binary data directly instead of encoding it as JSON. JSON will inherently be radically inefficient for sending a large dataset compared to sending encoded binary.

Edit: It looks like socket.io *can* send binary data so I would explore that along with some kind of efficient encoding/decoding scheme tailored to your dataset.

Comment: I don't need JSON. Socket.io should support binary data, but I'm not familiar with it.